# CKeditor does not show icons properly

Tags: entities, wysiwyg

[image]

The exact problem is that the editor doesn't show all the Toolbar icons. also, these that it does show, are black and white icons. something works wrong there...

Tried to change fields - didn't help. tried to go through all the options and re-save them, didn't help either. ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you recently updated ckeditor. The new version uses a black and white skin. There is also a know issue with updates and is noted in the issue queue. You need to go a resave all of your ckeditor profiles and flush drupal's cache, as well as your browser's cache.

Comment: Hey Nigel. didn't understand: "esave all of your ckeditor profiles". what do you mean?, and what will flusing the caches do? flush all Druapl caches didn't seem to help.

Comment: See https://drupal.org/node/1882396

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, this might be the problem/solution.  What has happened is you have installed the CK editor library as part of the drupal 7 WYSIWYG module/project. This only allows you to see this black and white editor.

http://johnathanthwaites.info/sites/default/files/toolbar.png

if you want the full editor including colour text, spell check and insert flash object etc etc. then you actually need to install CK editor *as a module* not as a library for wysiwyg. Then you get this one;

(Url above but image is toolbar2.png)

Ive done a full explanation here;

http://johnathanthwaites.info/Ckeditor

Comment: Please copy the important pieces from the linked article and include in your answer. Just in case the site is unavailable for any reason.